# Make script that reads argument from command line

Tags: bash, arguments

I am running quantum chemical calculations by providing the command `molcas -f file.input`. I now have need for putting the `molcas -f` into a script that also `tail`s the last 100 lines of the generated file.log, for me to quickly confirm that everything finished the way it's supposed to. So I want to run the script `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

molcas -f [here read the file.input from command line]
tail -100 [here read the file.log]
```

The question is how I can make the script read the argument I give, and then find on its own the output file (which has the same filename, but with a different extension).

---

Follow-up

Say I have a bunch of numbered files `file-1, file-2, ..., file-n`. I would save time if I instead of running

`./run.sh file-1.input file-1.log`

I  run

```
./run.sh n n
```

or

```
./run.sh n.input n.log
```

assuming that the actual filename and placement of the number `n` is given in the script. Can that be done?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/4797/internal-variables/16884/1-2-3-etc#t=201703091327041201335 and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/502/shell-parameter-expansion/7580/replace-pattern-in-string#t=201703091327440062742

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
molcas -f "$1"
tail -100 "$2"
```

You will need to execute the script run.sh as follows:

```
./run.sh file.input file.log
```

Comment: @Yoda Can you update with an example of desired input and output?

Answer (score 0):

to be hornest I have/had no clue over `molcas`, so I jumed to [this side](http://www.molcas.org/documentation/manual/node21.html) to get basic understandings.

The syntax shoould look like this ...

```
#!/bin/bash

# waiting for input
read -p "Enter a filename (sample.txt): " FILE

# checking for existing file
if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
    read -p "Enter a command for moculas: " CMD
else
    echo "Sorry, \"${FILE}\" was not found. Exit prgramm."
    exit 1
fi

# I am not sure how this command works.
# maybe you have to edit this line by your self.
molcas  $FILE -f "$CMD"

# checking for programm-errors
ERRNO=$?
if [ "$ERRNO" != "" ] && [ "$ERRNO" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Molcas returned an error. Number: ${ERRNO}"
    exit 1
fi


# cuts off the fileending (For example: sample.txt gets sample)
FILENAME="${FILE%.*}"

# checking other files
ERRFILE="${FILENAME}.err"
tail -n 100 $ERRFILE

LOGFILE="${FILENAME}.log"
tail -n 100 $LOGFILE


exit 0
```

I would have posted more, but its not clear what to do with this data.

Hope this helps a bit.